# Splice an array ref

Tags: arrays, linux, perl, splice

If I have an array reference how can I do a:
`splice($array, 0, $num);` since splice should not be used on array refs according to the documentation?
**Update:** My problem with that is that I do the splice on an array ref that I pass in a function so on exit the array is not modified.

**Update**
If I do `splice(@$array, 0 ,$num)` does this break the recommendation not to use an array ref in splice? I am confused on this. This snippet works for me (for an array ref that I pass in a function and I splice) but I am not sure if @$array is against the docs

Comment: The original question made sense, the update doesn't - `splice` modifies in-place.

Comment: *@$array is against the docs* - of course it's not. ) Why should the sub care about how exactly you get an array for it to process? The docs mention `splice $array_ref...` case as experimental.

Comment: Here's the [demo](https://eval.in/235276) based on your edit - as you see, it works just fine. Look elsewhere (and don't forget about `use warnings; use strict;` magic. )

Answer (score 3):

Use it on the derefenced arrayref instead:

```
my $arr = [1,2,3];
splice @$arr, 0, 1, 3, 4;
print join '-', @$arr; # 3-4-2-3
```

It's actually the same approach with `join` here - when used on arrayref, just dereference it.

It works the same way inside the sub obviously:

```
sub splice_it {
  splice @{$_[0]}, 0, 1, 3, 4;
}

my $arr_ref = [1,2,3];
splice_it $arr_ref;
print join '-', @$arr_ref; # still 3-4-2-3
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/235264).

---

Oh, and there's a big chance you actually are able to splice arrayrefs *directly* (without derefencing) - but please [just don't](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

> Starting with Perl 5.14, splice can take scalar EXPR, which must hold
>   a reference to an unblessed array. The argument will be dereferenced
>   automatically. This aspect of splice is considered highly
>   experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of
>   Perl.
>
> To avoid confusing would-be users of your code who are running earlier
>   versions of Perl with mysterious syntax errors, put this sort of thing
>   at the top of your file to signal that your code will work only on
>   Perls of a recent vintage:
>
> ```
> use 5.014;    # so push/pop/etc work on scalars (experimental)
> ```

It's still there, though: the same behaviour with `use 5.020;`

Answer (score 1):

You should dereference the array reference (`@$array` or `@{$array}`),

```
splice(@$array, 0, $num);
```

Comment: My problem with that is that I do the splice on an array ref that I pass in a function so on exit the array is not modified.

Comment: If I derefence won't I break the recommendation?

Comment: @Jim you'll change original array which was passed to your function, if that is what you're asking. Your question is not clear, in a sense what you have so far, and what behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: I understand what I did wrong. I will update the OP for my question.

Comment: @Jim it is NOT against perldoc recommendation. It states that using `$array` is experimental, and `@$array` is dereferenced array and thus recommended and not experimental at all.